# temporary remove all of the added paths in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have added a lot of paths to matlab and now I want to share my code, but I don't know exactly which function (in which path) I should add to my shared code. Each time I need to add a missing function and it is really bothering for me and the users who are using the code.

So, I would like to restore the matlab path to its original case. Is there any way to do this in matlab? I also want to keep a backup of my current added path in a .m file and use it later when I am done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To restore the path to default value - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/restoredefaultpath.html

> **restoredefaultpath** sets the search path to include only folders for
>   MathWorks® installed products. Use restoredefaultpath when you are
>   having problems with the search path.
>
> **restoredefaultpath; matlabrc** sets the search path to include only
>   folders for MathWorks installed products and corrects search path
>   problems encountered during startup.

And to save the current path - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savepath.html

> **savepath** updates the MATLAB® search path for all users on the system
>   so that the path can be reused in a future session. savepath saves the
>   search path to the pathdef.m file that MATLAB located at startup, or
>   to the current folder if a pathdef.m file exists there.

Or you can just store path in variable `p = path;` and restore it later `path(p);`. If the path is saved into `pathdef.m` the call of `pathdef` returns the string that can be used to set the saved path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, first I save the paths in a .m file and then I will restore to default mathworks directory. So, how I should restore to my customized path when I was done? I mean, how I can paste the saved paths to the matlab current path .m?

Comment: @Sam `pathdef` returns the string that can be used to set the path. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, I think the file can be edited in pathdef.m which is in matlabroot/toolbox/local

Comment: @Sam read carefully the manual `savepath saves the search path to the pathdef.m file that MATLAB located at startup, or to the current folder if a pathdef.m file exists there.` Create the local file and Matlab will save into it.